# 17.04 - No analog (audio) output

Tags: sound

I just updated from 16.10 to 17.04 and my Built-in Audio now has no analog output option, only Digital Stereo. Analog input is accepted. Under 16.10, I had the choice between analog output and Digital Stereo. The output pull-down only lists s/pdif. Now what?

Comment: What is the output `sudo aplay -l` - do you know what sound card your computer users?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replying. I'd lost track of the question's full location.

I finally got audio working, but, in part, I don't understand why.

The fix was to move the speaker/PC cable to the card's line out jack. When I did that, the Sound tool said I had an analog out port. At that point, everything worked.

But I don't understand why the sound card wasn't marked as having analog out when the jack was a speaker jack (vs. in the line out jack).

I'm happy I got things going, but IMHO tying the board's output options to what's plugged is... not unlike the intake end of a vacuum cleaner switched on.